# WebGL: exp() is insanely inaccurate

Tags: glsl, webgl, webgl2

I just did a loop over numbers from 1 to 50 and printed out WebGL's calculation of exp(float). I am using highp precision and these are from WebGL2.

```
   precision highp float;
    varying vec2 TexCoords;
    uniform highp sampler2D A;

    void main() {
      float result = exp(texture2D(A, TexCoords).r);
      gl_FragColor.r = result;
    }
```

I ran the same thing in javascript and compared the results. Things smart very small but quickly add up to very very large numbers.

So I also compared the results from javascript to python (numpy) and they are very comparable.

Here are the lat few numbers from the Math.abs(diff):

> Diffs', '8.25484005595456e-8,
>   3.700182968913168e-7,
>   0.0000037810978241736848,
>   0.0000055018942362039525,
>   0.000003128868712565236, ... 12720537652, 21883728284, 30738633104, 20683268800, 324543434496, 2989835245824, 6539001840640,
>   12329169293312, 110431739568128, 262788127178752, 615023709454336,
>   1369528883085312, 3028196912005120

These are the last few diffs between javascript and pyton
:

> 3.0517578125e-05
>   6.103515625e-05
>   0.0
>   0.0 ...
>   0.0
>   0.0
>   0.0
>   0.0
>   0.0
>   32.0
>   0.0
>   0.0 ...
>   0.0
>   0.0
>   0.0
>   262144.0

These are the first few numbers from the WebGL program:

> 'Results from WebGL',
>   '2.7182817459106445,7.3890557289123535,20.085533142089844,

and from javascript:

> 'Results from javascript',
>   '2.718281828459045,7.38905609893065,20.085536923187668,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a **WebGL** user so I might be wrong but Your differences suggest that only first `6-7` digits are correct for **WebGL**. That sounds about right for `32bit` float precision (only `23bits` of mantissa)

The **javascript** results are correct in first 16 digits that corresponds to `64bit` `double` so you are most likely comparing `32bit` vs. `64bit` computations so no surprise its less precise.

Here comparison:

```
WebGL     : 2.7182817459106445 ,7.3890557289123535 ,20.085533142089844  ,
javascript: 2.718281828459045  ,7.38905609893065   ,20.085536923187668  ,
PI float  : 2.71828174591064453,7.38905572891235352,20.08553504943847656,
PI double : 2.71828182845904509,7.38905609893064952,20.08553692318766437,
x87 double: 2.7182818284590451 ,7.3890560989306504 ,20.0855369231876679 ,
```

First two lines are your numbers. The `PI` lines are computed with consequent multiplication of `e` constant computed with **x87** on `32bit` and `64bit`. The last line uses **x87 FPU** internal `e^x` implementation `80bit -> 64bit`.

As you can see **WebGL** correlates with `32bit` floats very closely backing up my conclusions.

Comment: What you're saying makes a lot of sense. I went back and tried to use Float32Array to force javascript come up with more compatible answers but it didn't make a lot of difference. I also used pow(e,x) instead and the results weren't any better. We'll just have to take it as is.

Comment: @JeffSaremi on PC usually x87 FPU is used and its internal number representation is 80bit so even if you use exp on 32bit float the 80 bit instruction is used and the result is truncated to 32bit format. On GPU there is only 32bit (or even less) so the exp itself is less precise in comparison to 80 bit. If you want to check the difference compute `e^x` your self like `for (result=1.0,i=0;i<=x;i++) result*=M_E;` and once use float and then double ... Of coarse this is naive approach and shift&square will be more precise but it will show you the difference. real exp should use log2,exp2 approach